# Need help parsing xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

```
<ProductCatalog>
  <product>
    <AtrrList>
      <element Name="Storage Capacity" Value="8 GB"/>
      <element Name="Interface" Value="USB 2.0"/>
    </AtrrList>
  </product>  
</ProductCatalog>
```

This is xml that i need to parse, and i need Name and Value from element tag to put in array using loop.I have managed to read lines in php

```
foreach ($xxml->AttrList->element as $rating) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    $name = $rating['Name'];
    echo $name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $value = $rating['Value'];
    echo $value;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

but i just can't put that in array so i could save it into mysql database.

i would appreciate any help.

Comment: The result is apparently already an array (`$rating`), so you can just save that to your database if you'd want.

Comment: Explain **exactly** what you want to put in an array

Comment: Heres an example using **simplexml** in php (files and strings): http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html

Comment: Thank you oldskool, like i was blind all the time.I have all info i need in $rating,but i was working too much in past days so i dont think properly...thank you again.

Comment: $xxml is my variable with xml in it.

Comment: i was using SimpleXMLElement Carlos.But thank you, it will be very helpfull to read.

Comment: I feel the same as sometimes focusing too much and lose focus that something seems complicated is actually simple

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SimpleXML to get the values:

```
<?php

$xmlstr = <<<OOT
    <ProductCatalog>
    <product>
    <AtrrList>
    <element Name="Storage Capacity" Value="8 GB"/>
    <element Name="Interface" Value="USB 2.0"/>
    </AtrrList>
    </product>  
    </ProductCatalog>
OOT;

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach($movies->product->AtrrList->element as $attr)
{
    echo $attr['Name'].' '.$attr['Value'];
    echo '<p>---</p>';
}
```

This code will output:

```
Storage Capacity 8 GB
---

Interface USB 2.0
---
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse through the data!

Try this:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<ProductCatalog>
    <product>
        <AtrrList>
            <element Name="Storage Capacity" Value="8 GB"/>
            <element Name="Interface" Value="USB 2.0"/>
        </AtrrList>
    </product>  
</ProductCatalog>
EOD;

$rating = array();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $xml );
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'element' ) as $node ) {
    $rating[] = array(
        'name'  => $node->getAttribute( 'Name' ),
        'value' => $node->getAttribute( 'Value' ) );

    // You can output the attributes directly
    echo '<tr><td>'
        . $node->getAttribute( 'Name' )
        . '</td><td>'
        . $node->getAttribute( 'Value' )
        . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Now the result will be stored in $rating

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xml_parse_into_struct().

This function converts all xml elements to a multidimensional array.

i've no problems when i using it.

Check more info at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php